# DataTable Jquery - Th field Sort Image Issue

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

Have an UI issue while using DataTable Jquery. Please Check in the image - Department header sort image .  [image: check the attached image]

My Code is

```
 <table id="Report" border="1" class="display">
  <tread>
 <th>Project Code</th>
 <th>Department </th>
  </tread>
</table>
```

In Script :

```
Report.dataTable({
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "bInfo": false,                          
        "bFilter": false,                
        "bPaginate": false,              
        "bSortClasses": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "mData": "projectCode" },
                        { "mData": "department" },
 ]
    });
```

Everything is working. But the Sort icon is coming over the TH header ie - Department. 
Thanks in Advance.

Vinod

Comment: Did you include the corresponding CSS ? It appear to be a design problem...

Comment: Thanks Mat, yep Css file was missing. Updated it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Define width for thead fields
And you can change arrow position in

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc::after {
    content: "";
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc::after {
    content: "";
}
```

class in
dataTables.bootstrap.css